# Spring RestController + JPA Repository: How to work with different sets parameters in query?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-restcontroller, spring-repositories

I have RestController findAll() that can get different sets of parameters. For example:

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<List<? extends ParameterAbstract>> findAllParameters(boolean fullObjects, Long typeReportsId, boolean basicGroupParameters, Long groupParametersId) {
    List<Parameter> parameters = parameterService.findAll(typeReportsId, basicGroupParameters);
    //...
}
```

In my case, I have two right sets of parameters for my Repository that are passed by a client:

1. typeReportsId, basicGroupParameters - I search parameters that are in a basic group and belong typeReport
2. groupParametersId - I search parameters that are in a groupParameters

So I have two different methods of my Repository.
There may be more.

I thought that I can overload methods in my Service, but how can I recognize sets of parameters that were received in RestController? If I will check all possible sets it will take a long time and will fallible.

Comment: use polymorphism in method argument @Body it should work

Answer (score 1):

What about overriding repo's method in a Controller, implementing JpaSpecification and calling repo's method findAll(your specification) (or calling Services method, which calls repo's one)?
In the specification you can control how different sets of params get translated into SQL.
Link [enter link description here](https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2019/09/spring-data-jpa-specifications-example.html)

Comment: Thank you! I think It's the right thing. I found such an option of implementation: [REST Query Language with Spring Data JPA Specifications](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-language-spring-data-specifications)